# What is the difference between bins when using groupby apply vs resample apply?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, downsampling, pandas-resample

This is somewhat of a broad topic, but I will try to pare it to some specific questions.

I have noticed a difference between `resample` and `groupby` that I am curious to learn about.  Here is some hourly time series data:

```
In[]:
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020 8:00', periods=10, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10),
                   'B':range(10,20),
                   'C':range(20,30)}, index=dr)
df

Out[]:
                     A   B   C
2020-01-01 08:00:00  0  10  20
2020-01-01 09:00:00  1  11  21
2020-01-01 10:00:00  2  12  22
2020-01-01 11:00:00  3  13  23
2020-01-01 12:00:00  4  14  24
2020-01-01 13:00:00  5  15  25
2020-01-01 14:00:00  6  16  26
2020-01-01 15:00:00  7  17  27
2020-01-01 16:00:00  8  18  28
2020-01-01 17:00:00  9  19  29
```

I can downsample the data using either `groupby` with a `freq` `pandas.Grouper` or `resample` (which seems the more typical thing to do):

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2H'))
r = df.resample(rule='2H')
```

My impression was that these two were essentially the same thing (and correct me if I am wrong but `resample`*is* a rebranded `groupby`)?  But I have found that when using the `apply` method of each grouped object, you can index specific columns in the "DataFrameGroupBy" `g` object but not the "Resampler" object `r`:

```
def foo(d):
    return(d['A'] - d['B'] + 2*d['C'])

In[]:
g.apply(foo)

Out[]:
2020-01-01 08:00:00  2020-01-01 08:00:00    30
                     2020-01-01 09:00:00    32
2020-01-01 10:00:00  2020-01-01 10:00:00    34
                     2020-01-01 11:00:00    36
2020-01-01 12:00:00  2020-01-01 12:00:00    38
                     2020-01-01 13:00:00    40
2020-01-01 14:00:00  2020-01-01 14:00:00    42
                     2020-01-01 15:00:00    44
2020-01-01 16:00:00  2020-01-01 16:00:00    46
                     2020-01-01 17:00:00    48
dtype: int64

In[]:
r.apply(foo)

Out[]:
#long multi-Exception error stack ending in:
KeyError: 'A'
```

It looks like the data `d` that the `apply` "sees" is different in each case, as shown by:

```
def bar(d):
    print(d)

In[]:
g.apply(bar)

Out[]:
                     A   B   C
2020-01-01 08:00:00  0  10  20
2020-01-01 09:00:00  1  11  21
... #more DataFrames corresponding to each bin

In[]:
r.apply(bar)

Out[]:
2020-01-01 08:00:00    0
2020-01-01 09:00:00    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
2020-01-01 10:00:00    2
2020-01-01 11:00:00    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
... #more Series, first the bins for column "A", then "B", then "C"
```

However, if you simply iterate over the Resampler object, you get the bins as DataFrames, which seems similar to `groupby`:

```
In[]:
for i, d in r:
    print(d)

Out[]:
                    A   B   C
2020-01-01 08:00:00  0  10  20
2020-01-01 09:00:00  1  11  21
                     A   B   C
2020-01-01 10:00:00  2  12  22
2020-01-01 11:00:00  3  13  23
                     A   B   C
2020-01-01 12:00:00  4  14  24
2020-01-01 13:00:00  5  15  25
                     A   B   C
2020-01-01 14:00:00  6  16  26
2020-01-01 15:00:00  7  17  27
                     A   B   C
2020-01-01 16:00:00  8  18  28
2020-01-01 17:00:00  9  19  29
```

The printout is the same when iterating over the DataFrameGroupBy object.

**My questions based on the above?**

- Can you access specific columns using `resample` and `apply`?  I thought I had code where I did this but now I think I am mistaken.
- Why does the `resample` `apply` work on Series for each column for each bin, instead of `DataFrames` for each bin?

Any general comments about what is going on here, or whether this pattern should be encouraged or discouraged, would also be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [Resampler.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply.html). This is actually an alias for [Resampler.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) which is only capable of performing row-wise transformation. What that means is that resample.apply can only aggregate data across rows. So a function like `foo` will not make sense because it does not aggregate data.

Comment: @cs95 Gotcha!  So you can't `apply` `foo` on a resample object.  But you *could* "apply" `foo` by iterating over the object itself (my last code block)?  Which seems silly if you could use `groupby` (or just make a better non-loop version)